# Logrotate and "insecure permissions": What can actually go wrong?

Tags: linux, logrotate

Logrotate complained to me this morning that it would not rotate some logs because their parent directory  is writeable by someone else than root. The man page states I can make the error message go away by adding the "su" directive which makes logrotate drop root privileges when rotating that specific logfile. So far, so good.

What I wonder is (and the manpage is silent about it), how could a malicious user exploit logrotate if it would not take this precaution? As long as logrotate's configuration can only be altered by root (well, the configuration for logrotate that is triggered by cron and runs as root), an attacker cannot make logrotate touch arbitrary files, and I would assume logrotate does not touch symlinks?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this question too. It is really strange that you can't run logrotate except as root -- even when you provide a different location for the state file. With so many other processes creating log files, rather than relying on their logger configurations for rotation, it would be nice to use logrotate.

Answer (score 1):

One possible attack is creating a hardlink to a file that only root can access and have `logrotate` access that file.

While simple rotation would cause no harm (think doing rotation with just `mv(1)` and `rm(1`)), many directives will make `logrotate` read or write the file or pass it to a subprocess (`copytruncate`, `mail`, `shred`, etc.), so access to a copy of the file can be gained or the original file can be modified.

Note that this type of attack can be prevented using the [protect_hardlinks sysctl](https://sysctl-explorer.net/fs/protected_hardlinks/) that most (all?) distributions currently enforce, but this could still happen on custom-built kernels or if the administrator needed it disabled for some reason.